# Declaration of pointer to an array - access issue

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The nearest question on this website to the one I have had a few answers that didn't satisfy me.

Basically, I have 2 related questions :

Q. If I do something like :

```
char a[]= "abcde"; //created a string with 'a' as the array name/pointer to access it.

a[0]='z';  //works and changes the first character to z.
```

But

```
char *a="abcde";
a[0]='z'; //run-time error.
```

What is the difference? There is no "const" declaration, so I should be free to change contents, right?

Q. If I do something like :

```
int i[3];
i[0]=10; i[1]=20; i[2]=30;
cout<<*++i;  //'i' is a pointer to i[0], so I'm incrementing it and want to print 20.
```

This gives me a compile-time error, and I don't understand why.

On the other hand, this works :

```
int *i=new int[3];
i[0]=10; i[1]=20; i[2]=30;
cout<<*++i;  //Prints 20.
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not needing `const` is a special rule that was dropped in C++11. That still doesn't mean it's modifiable.

Comment: There must be hundreds of duplicates of this question...

Comment: After incrementing `i` in the second half of the second question, you no longer have a pointer that can be passed to `delete[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Q

```
char *a="abcde";
a[0]='z'; //run-time error.
```

Ans - Here `a` is pointing to string literal stored in read only location. You cannot modify string literal

Q

```
int i[3];
i[0]=10; i[1]=20; i[2]=30;
cout<<*++i;
```

Ans- Array and Pointers are not same thing. Here `i` is not a pointer. 
You need lvalue for increment operand

You can do :

```
int *p = &i[0];
std::cout<<*++p;
```

In last case operator `new` returns a pointer to a allocated memory space, so its possible.

Answer (score 1):

#### Question 1

The trouble is that it is still const.

A string literal actually has the type `char const*`.
But when they designed C++03 they decided (unfortunately) that conversion from `char const*` to `char*` is not an error. Thus the code:

```
char *a="abcde";
```

Actually compiles without error (even though the string is const). BUT the string literal is still a const even though it is being pointed at via a non const pointer. Thus making it very dangerous.

The good news is that most compilers will generate a warning:

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’

#### Question 2

```
cout<<*++i;  //'i' is a pointer to i[0], so I'm incrementing it and want to print 20.
```

At this point i is not a pointer. It's type is still an array.
It is not a valid operation to increment array.

The thing you are thinking about; is that arrays decay into pointers at the drop of a hat (like when you pass them to functions). Unfortunately that is not happening in this situation and thus you are trying to increment an array (which does not make sense).